# Bootstrap modal failing to display data with IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, bootstrap-modal

I have several Bootstrap3 modals. The code for a table is put into a javascript variable ‘html’, which is then displayed in the modal

```
$(document).ready(function () {var html='<table>
…….Table code goes here………….</TABLE></div>';
 $('#posttable').html(html) 
});
```

Using Jquery this code is inserted into a span

```
<span id="posttable"></span>
```

This works fine  when you access the  html  page directly
http://www.christmas-cards.org.uk/modals/postage.html

However --- with IE11 --- the table fails to show when viewed as a modal
http://www.christmas-cards.org.uk/     (click ‘Postage rates, countries & Last order dates’ near the top)

NB this happens only with  IE, everything works fine with Chrome + Firefox

Comment: Add, this script in <head></head>. Remember, this script should be before ending of </head> tag.
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion Nana, surely, however, htm5shiv and respond js are workarounds for IE  version prior to version 9. I'm testing with, and have the problem with, IE11.